# Algorithm Complexity loop

Tags: loops, complexity-theory

Time complexity of a triple-nested loop

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        for(int k=j+1; k<n; k++)
```

I want to know the right solution of time complexity.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think it is? Please demonstrate a basic effort to have solved the problem before posting it here.

Comment: Try to determine the number of iterations of the first loop, and for each iteration of the first loop, the number of iterations of the second one, and so on... Also, the overall complexity will depend on the complexity of the body of the third loop, but you can leave that for the end. You can try drawing a tree, it may be easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formal solution to determine the order of growth of your algorithm:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First guess: three loops depending on `n`, so it should be `O(n³)`

If you try to compute the exact complexity you have to compute it for the inner an multiply it with the outer loop.

inner loop takes `O(n-k)`
middle loop takes `O(n-j + n-j-1 + ... + n-j-n) = O((n-j) ⋅ (n-j+1) / 2) = O((n-j)²)`
outer loop takes `O((n-1)² + (n-2)² + ... + (n-n+1)²) = O(n³)`

Sure this is not exact, but in terms of big-O it is exact enought.